# React. Store JSX class component and change it's props later

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-component

Im developing a react image editor, and I want to draw lines on the canvas, to do this I have a  class that i add to the canvas elements array (this stores all the diferent elements, text, images and lines that the canvas redraws every frame).

But when i do this:

```
let pos = this.stageRef.current.getPointerPosition()
let new_line = (<Line
                  key={this.state.itemArray.length}
                  stroke={'#df4b26'}
                  strokeWidth={5}
                  globalCompositeOperation={'source-over'}
                  points={[pos.x, pos.y]}
                />)
this.state.itemArray.push(new_line)

this.setState({isDrawing: true})

console.log(new_line)
```

I get this object:

[image]

This object it's located inside the itemsArray, all the items are rendered on the main render here:

[image]

And it's rendered correctly, but all it's props are read-only and i can't call any methods of the object, what i need it's the "real" React object, the one you get when you call a reference.
(I want to add more points to the line object onMoveMouse event)

**this:**

[image]

Is there any way I can get the Line object (i just created) accesing to the itemsArray object instead of using the ref?

I don't know how can i create a Line object directly and call it's methods without a Ref ¿Do I really need a ref to an object i just created 2 lines above?.

Comment: You need to use a ref. The instance that you're after doesn't exist until later in the rendering lifecycle. The JSX you write just creates elements: instructions to react about what instances it should create.

Comment: But i don't understand, why later on when i call a ref to some item from the itemArray and change it (changing attrs or calling some method) it re-renders correctly if I didn't update the itemArray.

Comment: Are you setting state or something inside the Line instance? If so, that will cause it to rerender, even if nothing in the parent component changed.

Comment: Yeah but it also re-renders correctly when i re-render the whole parent component, for example when i add a new item to the array, the whole component gets re-rendered and all the items from the itemArray maintain the changes that i did to their Ref.current before the new item was added.

Comment: The array of elements is just instructions to react: "make me N Lists, with such and such props". On the first render, react takes the instructions and mounts corresponding components. Ie, it creates instances of the component. This instance is what your ref is interacting with. Instances have their own state, and can rerender independently. Second time you render the main component, you tell react "make me N + 1 Lists, with such and such props". Other than the one you added, the instances already exist, so they get reused. Their state won't be thrown out.

Comment: So. when the itemArray map it's re-called on the re-render React knows what items from the itemArray have already been rendered in the past and just don't execute the instructions again?
Why do they get deleted when I pop one out from the itemArray?